# Request information on: "You have made too many incorrect reviews"

Tags: support, review-audits, review-suspension

Recently I got a review ban for 3 days with error message:

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you should have reviewed differently.
>
> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post

First of all I would like to apologise if I have created any drawbacks.

If anyone can provide me more information on the mentioned message I would be glad to learn from my mistakes and do better reviews next time.

Is it possible know the full list of wrong reviews?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You appear to have a history of approving just about everything.

Many edits you approved are really too minor. When someone suggests an edit, we expect them to not waste the time of the reviewers by only addressing one problem, leaving other problems in place.

[The edit linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5234487) for example still has grammar and spelling issues; *How can I get Quotation mark by giving the ascii number* could have been corrected to *How can I get a quotation mark by giving the ASCII number*.

Some more edits:

- [This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5234413) did not remove the *Thanks!* salutation
- [This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5234410) only added a tag and did not correct the lack of capitalisation.
- [This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5234414) moved some of the question text into the code block and again did not address capitalisation issues
- [This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5217509) only added tags (with a misleading edit summary) but again did not address grammar issues.
- [This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5217493) replaced a link to an image with the text *Image here*; this is not exactly helpful or an improvement, and again other problems were left in place. The minimal thing to do here would have been to replace the link with the markdown for an inline image.
- [This edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5217492) added new code and a tag; how proficient are you in JavaScript to know if that additional code is innocent or perhaps making the question invalid now?

You also went against the [consensus on this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24294953/scroller-not-animating-without-browser-refresh), making the edit even worse; note the tag on the post, *Skrollr* is a library, the word in the title did not need correcting.

Other exceptions from your pattern are one audit you passed, and two counts where you did remove the 'thanks' left in by an editor (one of which I'd still have rejected as too minor), and one rejection of [this wiki excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5125875), which I personally would have approved (it is a perfectly valid excerpt for a tag).

Because you approve almost everything in sight, you also allowed [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5217458) to be made. That edit is a wholesale copy of the [text from the W3C standard](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5217458), and should have been rejected as plagiarism.

On the whole your reviewing patterns come over as a *Robo reviewer*; you are not paying enough attention and are approving even minor edits too easily, but you are paying *just* enough attention to not be fooled by audits. As such I think a moderator gave you a manual review ban.

Please be more selective in what small edits you approve.

Comment: Thanks for your details, I will do my best to improve my next reviews.

Comment: I believe we need to have a lit of rules or guidelines to help every reviewer and editor to be on the same page. Putting it on the review page would be one way to go about.

Comment: I thought minor edits were now OK?

Comment: @Raedwald nope, not that I'm aware of. Not for suggested edits.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252249/what-is-wrong-with-minor-edits

Comment: Found it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270961/disappearance-of-too-minor-where-is-the-relevant-discussion "too minor" was removed as a rejection reason.

Comment: Right, I forgot about that decision. As you can see from the voting the community doesn't quite agree.