# Disappearance of "too minor" -- where is the relevant discussion?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I just went to review suggested edits and found my set of rejection criteria reduced to the following:

- copied content
- invalid edit
- radical change
- vandalism
- custom

I assume the disappearance of "too minor" is deliberate policy -- either the option was removed entirely or perhaps it was set to a rep threshold higher than mine. Is there a discussion somewhere that would summarize the debate and explain the rationale for the change?

Comment: Wow, that's extraordinary.  Nice if you work for SE, you can get the most annoying complaining eliminated easily.  Gilles never disappoints.

Comment: What does Gilles have to do with this?  I don't see a diamond next to his name.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239106

Comment: Related (Shog9's solution for people rejecting too minor) http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238039/213963 --- "**Get rid of the "too minor" reject reason entirely.** If it's really too minor, reviewers should demonstrate that by providing a not-minor edit. If the reviewer opts to build upon the edit instead of starting over from the current revision, *then it isn't too minor!*"

Comment: @MichaelT Nah, they should just say "Other" and write "too minor". I'd like to see stats on the number of times each choice is used, but I'm willing to bet that "Too Minor" was near the top.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hans was commenting on the fact that Gilles was a particularly vocal advocate for the "encouraging lots of pointless edits" bandcamp.  He's expressing his disappointment that the section of the community supporting his viewpoint, that insubstantial edits that aren't adding value should be rejected, has not been valued merely because it has not complained as loudly.  At least, that's what it sounds like to me.

Comment: @TylerH: That's a really good way to have the Custom option taken away.

Comment: @RobertHarvey do it if you think it's an improvement; see what the community thinks. Who is in charge of the direction of the site? The community or the moderators/site owners?

Comment: @TylerH: I have no authority over the software whatsoever, so your retort makes no sense.  It's SE's sandbox, so draw your own conclusions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sorry: it wasn't a retort, but an actual suggestion. My guess is, if the Custom option gets abused as a catch-all (isn't that what it's *for*?) and ends up being removed, then users will start selecting "Invalid Edit" as their catch-all. Cat-and-mouse. The "Too minor" option was specific, valid, and useful. It only makes sense that people will find another tool to fill the need.

Comment: According to "[What guidance should be given when edits are rejected?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238333)", 'too minor' was indeed the most-used reason, @TylerH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relevant discussion can be found here: [Approve as too minor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039)

The big problem with "too minor" is... No one agreed on what it meant. Totally pointless? Useful but with some work left undone? Under *X* characters, where *X* is between 6 and 600? After *many years* of mostly-fruitless discussion toward resolving this, I decided "can be blithely discarded in favor of a better edit" makes as much sense as anything - so, that's now baked into the UI: if you use the "Reject and Edit" review option, your edit will *replace* the edit you're reviewing, rejecting it in the process:

The results look [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5726374):

[image]

That rejection reason *is* the replacement for "too minor", clarifying it according to the criteria outlined above. It is usable only by Community, and only triggered by "Reject and Edit" reviews.

The rest of the canned rejection reasons could use some love too... If you have suggestions, drop them here: [What guidance should be given when edits are rejected?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238333/what-guidance-should-be-given-when-edits-are-rejected)

Comment: Makes sense, but if you go removing all of the features that people don't agree on what they mean, there won't be much of anything left.

Comment: So if a post is kind of flawless except for a tiny spelling mistake and correcting this is a suggested edit then since there isn't really anything one could add, it should be accepted?

Comment: @Trilarion Of course. Correcting spelling errors _improves the post_.

Comment: If a post is *truly flawless*... save for one flaw... that an edit corrects... Then hell yeah you should approve that edit, @Trilarion.

Comment: @Shog9 Yes I thought so because it is the borderline example of what you laid out. I thought it was handled differently in the past and I saw edits rejected but maybe I'm mistaken. Just for fun I searched for "the the" with [google](https://www.google.de/search?hl=de&as_q=&as_epq=%22the+the%22&as_oq=&as_eq=amazon&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=stackoverflow.com&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=) because this is a very common mistake and found 168.000 (!) but then I clicked on them and the problem is that most of these are not otherwise truly flawless..I gave up.

Comment: "Truly flawless" is kind of a mythical beast, in my experience @Trilarion. But yes, the handling of suggested edits is notoriously inconsistent - hence the recent efforts to change how it works.

Comment: @Shog9 And what if a post is a complete pile of crap, editing it into a good post is likely impossible, and just fixing most of what is fixable would likely take a good 10-20 minutes, and someone comes along and removes the "thanks" from the end.  Is the reviewer now obligated to spend 20 minutes editing the post (to which the review will with 100% certainty get approved while this editing takes place) just to get the edit rejected?

Comment: No one is obliged to do anything, @Servy. But one might reject such an edit with a custom reason ("please try to actually improve the post in some way"), reject it with a partial edit, or... just skip it and leave it to someone else. For the future, I'm kinda liking [this suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238333/what-guidance-should-be-given-when-edits-are-rejected/239138#239138) for a canned reason.

Comment: @Shog9 If we can't get people to reject those edits when there's an actual system defined reason for it, what makes you think you'll actually get 3 reviewers to reject the edit using a custom reason?  The edit shouldn't be skipped, it should be rejected.  If the reviewer conclusively knows that it should be rejected and why they should be able to reject the post, they shouldn't be skipping it.  *None* of the reviewers should be *obligated* to put in the rather large investment in time to completely fix up a train wreak of a post just to reject an equally terrible edit.

Comment: @Shog9 Since the only practical option you've left available is to approve the edits, that's what you'll get.  And with no practical way of rejecting edits for being minor, you'll remove any incentive for editors to make substantial edits.  I mean why spend 20 minutes actually fixing a post when you could just remove the "thanks" instead and get the same +2 rep.

Comment: I'd also like to take a second to point out that if [we remove the rep incentive to post bad/minor edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239143/186381), so that the people actually editing posts will be primarily people with an actual intrinsic motivation to improve the posts, can at least ensure that a lot of people aren't submitting these edits, even if we can't reject them.

Comment: That, I could get behind @Servy. Beyond that, I'll note that what you're really after here is some sort of "made NO improvements whatsoever" rejection reason, which is fair - again, see the discussion I linked to regarding revamping the rest of these reasons.

Comment: The first order effect of this change should be "when an edit is reviewed, it is more likely to be approved than before", as it discourages rejecting an edit.  The second order effect is it should discourage people who used to reject "too minor" edits from reviewing, magnifying the first order effects.  Assuming the designer of the change intended these effects, the position is "we want more minor edits to be approved, there was too much rejection of them under the pre-existing system".  Is that accurate?

Comment: Not really, @Yakk - more along the lines of, "we want reviewers to feel strongly about decisions that are made". The problem with a vague rejection reason is that it becomes a path of least resistance - approving edits has *always* been the easiest review action, but rejecting with a vague reason is a close second. If you're gonna reject, you should have a good reason for it - and with these changes, if you're willing to back that up with an edit you're practically guaranteed it will take effect.

Comment: @shog9 If you want to make people think harder, removing the path of 2nd least resistance is a bad plan.  That'll reduce the robo-rejectors (which ... again, I assume they exist?  The quality of edit that actually gets a rejection is so low in my experience that I'm wondering...), but increase the robo-acceptors (some of the lazy rejectors will just say "meh, I'll just accept").

Comment: Again, "accept" is *already* the easiest review, @Yakk. If you're out to blow through a review as quickly as possible with no other considerations, then you're not even noticing an option to reject is missing... If you *do* care, even a little bit, then you have some new options, with more coming - but they do actually require you to think.

Comment: @Shog9 But that's just it.  As a reviewer I can spend the time, think through the proper course of action, determine that a review is completely pointless and not adding value, *but I can no longer reject the review for that reason*, even after spending that time to determine that it's not adding value.  You didn't edit the wording of "too minor" to make it less vague and give it stricter guidelines that require more evidence, *you removed the reason entirely, preventing posts from being rejected for that reason*.

Comment: @Servy You can still do it with a cuatom reason. Hopefully that will prevent trigger-happy rejections with that reason.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I could, but no item I ever voted to reject would ever actually get rejected without a stock "too minor" reason because there would never be two other people rejecting it with a custom reason.

Comment: @Servy ...which just goes to show that people don't actually believe in such rejects but as just being shoehorned into it. If the masses really thought as ypu do then they would follow your rejections regardless. Don't try to grab control over the mindless reviewdrones for your own ends please!

Comment: This points to a systemic problem with review, which I put firmly at the feet of too many bad canned rejection reasons - so the solution is to fix *that*. @Servy

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, it's a result of the fact that there is nothing anywhere to teach people how to review suggested edits.  The only guidance available to them is what rejection reasons there are. That's pretty much all that a reviewer has to work on to determine what should or shouldn't be rejected. That said, how in the world is it a *bad* thing for the system to encourage people to take actions that are beneficial to the site? If people's initial unguided reactions to a suggested edit is to *take an action that harms the site* then you're quite right I want to guide them elsewhere.\

Comment: @Servy As I've stated many times now, rejecting every spellcheck edit you see is _not_ beneficial for the site

Comment: @Shog9 There most certainly are major systematic problems with review.  All evidence I've seen indicates that this will only ever make things worse, probably pretty dramatically so over time.  This change is actively incentivizing editors to make lower quality edits, and it's removing the primary tool that reviewers have to reject those low quality edits.  It's also doing nothing to address what I consider the core problems with review, namely a lack of means for new reviewers to learn how to review *well*, incentives to review badly, and a lack of tools to detect/prevent/reverse bad reviews.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit An assertion to which you have provided *zero supporting evidence*.  You have refused to respond to all of the points that I have raised on the subject, instead merely asserting your position without backing it up in the slightest.  Saying your right over and over again doesn't make you right.  Your inability to even *attempt* to support your position is *significant* evident that you are in fact wrong.

Comment: @Servy: wtf? I've responded to every single one of your points, across many many comments. Also, your final sentence there is an obvious logical fallacy. Finally, there is no objective "right or wrong" here so you are just as guilty at asserting correctness as you accuse me of being. This discussion with you is _swiftly_ becoming nonconstructive as long as you insist on this malicious approach to debate. Simply put, I'm not going to continue with this farce until you can engage me without arrogance and rudeness.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You [openly admitted](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270961/disappearance-of-too-minor-where-is-the-relevant-discussion/270980?noredirect=1#comment93043_270971) to rejecting my points out of hand without reasoning, explanation, or evidence.  As to whether there is a right answer, there is a decision that's better for the site and one that's worse, so if you consider the site being better "right" then there is a right answer.  You're (once again) responding to the assertion that you're not supporting your position by *refusing to support your position*.

Comment: @Servy Total nonsense - the comment you linked to says I considered your points "carefully". You're bordering on slander, here. Be cautious. If I'm not bothering to defend my position any more then it's only because you're going out of your way to pretend that I haven't done so; therefore, there are much better things I can do with my time. Please read my answer and let's leave it at that now okay?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Considering the points doesn't mean that you explained your reasoning for ignoring them, explained why they should be ignored, nor is it providing evidence that they should be ignored.  You statement that I am slandering you is itself slander.  All of the points I just raised are 100% true.  The fact that you considered the points before ignoring them is in no way supporting evidence that they should be ignored.  Your opinion, without any support, that they should be ignored is just that, your unsupported opinion.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You haven't actually *said* much of anything.  Just about all of your comments have been deflections, your unsupported opinions, you saying time and time again that you're refusing to continue the conversation, you continually changing the topic to something unrelated which I have subsequently refuted, only to have that point too be ignored.  The only actual *evidence*, reasoning, or arguments that you've given as to why this change is good is your opinion that it will be good, nothing more.

Comment: @Servy So now _your_ points are 100% true... because you raised them. You're doing my nut in, mate. You are a hypocrite and an illogical individual. Indeed, as I've said, I'm not talking about this with you any more. It's entirely pointless. I made my case in several places throughout this question, but you keep on refusing to read it. It's so _rude_ and _obviously untrue_ that I don't understand how you are not embarassed by this!

Comment: Talking to you is like responding to comments on YouTube and I promise I will try to do a _better_ job of not continuing, since I admit you keep drawing me back in to defend myself against your nonsensical accusations.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not making that assertion.  I've provided several reasoned arguments for why this change is harmful, and provided evidence that this change will cause harm to the site.  You're more than welcome to consider those points, provide counter points, evaluate the validity of their assumptions or process.  That's how a discussion works.  Over time, everyone involved learns more about the topic, and possibly a consensus results.  You've done none of that.  You've asserted your opinion and refused to explain it or support it.

Comment: You two are just noisying up this comment thread now... If you really want to hash out something useful, [hop into chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta).

Comment: consider [edit]ing the answer to update it with details of recently introduced ["no improvements whatsoever"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240686/165773) reason. It probably wouldn't hurt to additionally address related question: [What do I now do for a previously “too minor” edit?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271552/839601)

Comment: That's why I wrote a blog post, @gnat; that said, folks who didn't bother clicking through to the discussion linked to in this answer from *day one* already cheated themselves out of the information they so desperately wanted. I'll take a look at the related question...

Comment: I see, thanks! link to that discussion indeed helps to refer up-to-date status, agreed

Answer (score 65):

I used "Too minor" tag to get rid of superficial edits that were done just to grab +2 rep. For me it was a synonym of an *unnecessary* edit.

What now? Use "Reject and edit" and possibly do minor changes ourselves just to restrain repo hunters?

It does not seem like a good idea at all.

**Part 2**

It was suggested in comments to use "invalid edit" instead.

Its definition seems to be:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

If someone deletes "Thank you" at the bottom of a post and does nothing else, I consider such edit *unnecessary* (not needed) and, in fact, *minor*.

The edit I just described is *not* incorrect (we don't really like any non-informative content), it's definitely neither a reply *nor* a comment.

It's just an insignificant, and therefore unnecessary, edit that needs to be rejected.  **Too minor** reason fit in such cases like a glove. Invalid edit?  I do not think so.

Comment: Too Minor suggests that the edit should be "substantial, addressing multiple issues in the post."  If you are rejecting edits that don't meet that metric, but then failing to make the substantial edit yourself, isn't that kinda the pot calling the kettle black?

Comment: @RobertHarvey That's a fallacious argument. An edit reviewer isn't obliged to make any edits himself at all. You don't have to lay an egg to be able to spot a rotten one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: What about a post that simply didn't need editing in the first place, and somebody did a trivial edit apparently to gain rep, with no improvement to the post at all?

Comment: @RobertHarvey : I believe you missed my point. I'm talking about cases when the post was basically OK "as is" and the edits that are not needed since they don't really improve anything.

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, it's called "I want to review edits, not make them". If I wanted to make edits I could open any arbitrary page and edit away.

Comment: Discussion moved here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239106

Comment: Rejecting an edit that removes "Thank you" is absurd. We do not want people to write "thank you" at the bottom of posts, therefore by our quality metric an edit that removes that text improves the post. Why do you not want to improve the post? Utterly absurd. It seems that you're just out to punish people for being "lazy" and not changing more about the post. But, hey, not every post _has_ more than that to fix. And if it does? Well, great, you _or someone else_ can fix that later. But that's no reason not to make the immediate improvement. No reason at all. It's also not your job to "punish".

Comment: I don't think it really matters if someone makes minor edits and gains 2 rep if there's really nothing else that could be done with the post. Eventually they'll hit 2k rep and they're doing things that we recommend doing anyways, like removing "thanks" or fixing a spelling error. It's not like the suggested edits queue is inundated anyways.

Comment: @nightcracker if there are other issues in the post, and you don't want to fix them as part of reviewing and editing, you could click 'skip'.

Comment: We need a new reject reason to replace "too minor" - "unnecessary" - the edit doesn't address or fix anything at all.

Comment: @slebetman there is still a custom field.

Comment: @MichaelT: Yes, but at some point in the future where 80%-90% of all "custom" refer to "unnecessary" I think it is worth while to re-introduce "too minor" only rename it "unnecessary". Note that this is also how I use "too minor" not to signify that I don't think the edit is complete but to signify that I don't think the edit has any reason to exist.

Comment: Some of the ones I used to keep rejecting is to respell words in American English. It used to be agreed that all forms of English spelling are acceptable here but some people just can't resist.

Comment: @MichaelT: Sorry.. ignore my rant. I just noticed "invalid edit".

Comment: @slebetman thus part of the confusion about what too minor means.  When someone changes dialectical spelling, reject it saying British English is fine as a custom reason.  When someone edits to retag an old closed post, say that that isn't helpful in the reject reason.

Comment: Before the "too minor" reason was removed, I already tried to improve minor edits. Unfortunately it was very common that while I was improving a minor edit, the edit had already been approved by other people, so that I couldn't apply my edit.

Comment: Ironically [this edit](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/270971/3) of the answer appears to be too minor to me.

Comment: @Michael Ehm, retagging old posts is fine. Posts are not just for the benefit of the original author, but for all current and future visitors. Hence, their quality is important. I'd say the same is true for some closed questions, though arguably all closed questions other than duplicates should be deleted.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've seen tag killing efforts where some <2k users are retagging or editing old, poor, closed posts (such as, hypothetically, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14260032) - upload and uploading? whats apc doing there?) where the proper thing to do is probably to delete the post instead. Without a significant amount of involvement from the OP of that example question, there is no amount of editing that can save the question and make it a good one. Many old [too localized](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14293596/289086) questions are particularly prone to this needless editing.

Comment: @ydae "Too minor" was never a thing for people with full editing privileges anyway. It applied *only* to suggested edits.

Comment: @MichaelT If the edit is _wrong_ then reject as "invalid". It is not " too minor".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit is it *wrong* to remove a tag that doesn't apply or fix the tags?  No.  It is not incorrect nor is it an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.  However, if the question is closed and no amount of editing will make it an openable question, then one should instead consider a [custom](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239100/213963) reason that explains that no amount of editing (short of the OP coming and *really* fixing it) is appropriate to the question.

Comment: @Michael Yeah ok that makes sense. _Still_ not a reason for "too minor". There's been lots of outcry on this thread about "too minor" being removed, yet nobody's yet been able to give me a valid example of its use!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit too minor was the one click proxy for a lot of different reasons before (just as many of the old close reasons). This is part of what was confusing... and people weren't taking the time to reject with a custom written one in part because sometimes when you wrote one that properly explained why you were rejecting it, it was reviewed already - no one ever saw it (other people clicked too minor more quickly than you typed it). With the changes to the review (a period of exclusivity) and the removal of the proxy, it allows people to write reject reasons that are descriptive.

Comment: @Michael Sounds like we're in agreement! Too minor was mostly misused. Those trying to defend it have little basis to do so.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The edit was too minor.  It was an edit that wasn't wrong, it was just adding zero value to the site.  That is the *definition* of too minor, an edit that's only flaw is not adding value, or not adding enough value.  While a custom reason, such as Michael's suggestion, explains *why* it's too minor, "too minor" is still what it is.

Comment: @Servy It did add value. Quite clearly. It fixed broken, uncomfortable language making the post easier to read and SO a tiny bit more professional-looking. Maybe it didn't make you rich or save five children in Africa, but it added value. The post is better now than it was before. If you're one of those people who doesn't think grammar, spelling or presentation have any value then this is not the right site for you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If the post is still completely unreadable, unanswerable, and has no value even after the edit then no, the edit didn't add value.  Do you go around cleaning up a building that's set for demolition later that day?  If you answer no, does that mean you're arguing against ever cleaning buildings and asserting that cleanliness isn't important?  No.

Comment: @Servy Oh, edits on totally unsalvagable posts is another matter entirely. I guess I'd support a custom reject in that case. But it's _obviously_ not the case on the post in question, which is now spot on thanks to that "too minor" edit.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Because the edit is too minor.  It is literally the *textbook definition* of too minor.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Which edit are you referring to?

Comment: @Servy the one linked to in this comment thread. if that's not the one _you_ meant by "the edit [was too minor]" in your comments above, then which? I don't see any others under discussion.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit There are several linked edits, and several hypotheticals discussed.  I don't see a single one that appears to have turned a bad post into a great one, so, due to my confusion, I'm asking you to clarify which edit you're referring to.  If I knew which one you were referring to I wouldn't have asked in the first place.

Comment: @Servy It seemed like an odd question since you had also been apparently talking about a specific edit until just now. Now suddenly you're confused by me doing just that. Odd. Especially as, despite your claim, there is only ONE in this particular thread. Anyway, it was [this one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270961/disappearance-of-too-minor-where-is-the-relevant-discussion/270971?noredirect=1#comment92083_270971)

Comment: Wait, no it wasn't, that one's poor. Now I'm confused. Hang on let me find it

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I thought I knew what we were talking about, but your last comment didn't make sense with what I had in mind, hence my question.  Let me know when you figure it out.

Comment: @Servy Meh I can't even find it now. Maybe it got deleted. I'll take a closer look later. For the record, the edit on this answer is also absolutely fine. It gets rid of the horrible, grating abuse of code formatting in several places as well as obnoxious overbolding, and thus improves the formatting of the post... and the experience of reading it. Is it minor? Yes, relatively. Is it _too_ minor? Absolutely not. Since we should not fundamentally alter the meaning/content of answers it seems that you would only accept a very select subset of all possible edits.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I don't consider the edit you just quoted as too minor.  It's also worth noting that it's not a suggested edit either.  That's significant.

Comment: @Servy Ah that's interesting. I make a point of applying the same rules to _all_ edits. I recognise that suggested edits having _any_ cost is as distinct to direct edits, but it feels unfair to the potential content improvement to discriminate on that basis.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Suggested edits have a greater cost to them than non-suggested edits.  They consequently have a higher bar in terms of the value that they need to add to have a net positive effect on the site.  Do you really think it's worth harming the site (by either approving suggested edits that have negative net worth or discouraging non-suggested edits that have a positive net worth) just so that you can assert that suggested edits and non-suggested edits aren't ever treated differently?  Is the equality actually that important?

Comment: @Servy Again I dispute that any real harm is evident. Improving content must surely be our primary goal.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I've listed quite a number of problems that they cause.  Are you asserting that those problems don't exist, or that they don't matter?  Up until now you've just deflected and avoided actually addressing any points specifically.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Improving content is certainly nice, but everything has costs.  Ignoring all of the costs and merely asserting that some action is good just because there is a gross positive effect without even considering the drawbacks is naive.  There are all sorts of things that we could do to improve content that would have costs far greater than the benefits received.  When evaluation an action you need to consider all of the consequences, not just one of them.

Comment: @Servy I did consider the effects, quite carefully, and then I dismissed them as trivial. I'm not "naive" and I'm not taking shortcuts; please don't assert ownership of the high ground here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So you're right because you say that you're right, without supporting your position, dismissing all counter points out of hand without any evidence, reasoning, or discussion, and without any supporting points of your own.  And you think that that's a compelling reason to take a particular course of action?  Really?  Are you serious?

Comment: @Servy I don't know if maybe there is some language barrier here; perhaps English is not your first language? But at _no_ point have I even _approached_ suggesting that "I'm right because I say I' right" or that I've dismissed all counter points "out of hand". Indeed, in the _very previous comment_ I said that I considered them carefully and you can see evidence of that in the 50 or so comments I've now written on the issue across this mess of a meta question. Come back when you're ready to have a mature, logical discussion instead of flinging around total nonsense.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You saying that you dismissed the comments because you considered them *is the very definition of dismissing them because you say you're right*.  The fact that you thought about what your opinion should be before asserting that your personal opinion is objective fact that you are right doesn't mean that you provided evidence, that is not a reasoned argument, and it is not a supporting point for your position.  It's just you saying your right and nothing else.  If you explained what you considered, why you considered those points, etc. *then* that would be an argument.

Answer (score 16):

I think this is fantastic. This notion that "you must fix most/all of a post's problems, or none at all" is totally ridiculous, and we can still reject edits that literally do not improve a post (i.e. rep grabbers doing no good) using "invalid edit" and such. Rep grabbers doing *good* should get the rep they deserve regardless of their intentions: offering rep for edits then saying that people should have edits rejected simply because their motivation is gaining rep, is just absurd.

However I think it's also important to clarify that, personally, I would neither expect nor require reviewers to start manually fixing the rest of the post's problems when they encounter an edit that only resolves *some* of those problems. There is no rule that says that people who give their time reviewing edits must now also give their time to *make* edits. Let's just keep it simple: does the edit improve the post? Yes? Accept it. Feel free to improve on it, but you certainly don't *have* to. Another editor will be along soon enough to finish off the job, and I'm quite sure that the SO database can handle there existing two revisions rather than one.

Comment: What if the edit improves a post so insignificantly that it's indeed too minor?

Comment: To use your example, an edit that does nothing but remove, "Thank you", but leaves *blantantly obvious spelling and grammar mistakes* is the epitome of too minor.  It's grabbing the low hanging fruit, for no other reason than rep.  At what point should a rejection *require* a reviewer's own input?  Just because you know the edit should be rejected doesn't mean you know how to go about improving it.

Comment: Did you mean "I would not expect nor require *reviewers* to" ?

Comment: @Ben Probably :-)

Comment: @PM Read my answer. There is no such thing. A tiny improvement is still an improvement. It's not a reviewers' job to act as judge jury and executioner on whether an editor should be rewarded or punished for an edit that does improve a post, however extensively.

Comment: @jb Grabbing low hanging fruit is perfectly acceptable, as is editing solely for rep. So I really don't see the problem beyond this campaign of people trying to "punish" others for not editing _more_. It's kind of sad, actually.

Comment: +1 -- there's no such thing as a "bad improvement," who cares about the two rep? If it makes SO a better place by even a tiny bit, let the edit through; if not, kill it for the appropriate reason.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - But then you just incentivise meaningless re-tagging campaigns such as adding the `t-sql` tag to all `sql-server` questions.

Comment: @Martin Either the tag is appropriate/correct for those questions, or it isn't. What's the problem? Why does it matter _how_ it was added if it's correct? And if it's not, use "invalid edit".

Comment: Nope, I disagree.  The whole point of Too Minor was users taking the easy way out.  If you're not actually fixing everything that should be fixed, and leaving obvious spelling mistakes, you can bet I'll be rejecting that all day long.  It's all about effort; fixing one little aspect without fixing other bits just shows little effort, and should not be rewarded.

Comment: I don't think the reason was listed as "you must fix every problem with this post", but rather that "this edit doesn't go far enough; there are still substantive errors remaining." I see lots of suggested edits where the only change is capitalization of a couple words (i --> I). Such minor edits should be left for when you are above 2K rep and don't need to take three peoples' attention away just to approve your incremental action.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's much less attention required to reject an edit than it is to improve (at which point you're no longer reviewing; you're editing). The point, however, is to avoid those kinds of suggested reviews from ever entering the queue in the first place.

Comment: @Tyler WHY? They IMPROVE the post. I don't know how to make this any clearer for you. And if you're choosing review actions on a leasteffort basis then you should not be reviewing at all (and certainly shouldn't be complaining that others aren't fixing as much as you'd like).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm not arguing from my personal point of view, but from the point of view of the behavior that StackOverflow encourages. They want gamification and ease-of-use, but nearly every interaction on the site is confused, at best. If I want to review edits, let me review edits. Maybe I don't have time to focus on substantive additions myself, but I do have time to check others' reviews (on a train going home, for example). Don't call it the "Review" Queue if half the "reviews" are going to require **edits** on my part. That's part of the beauty of having 3+ people review the..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit suggested edit; people with more time can provide improvements, and those who have a keen eye for appropriateness but no time (or they're on a phone without a qwerty keyboard) can reject with a simple, effective, and descriptive push of a button.

Comment: @Tyler Or they can accept the edit and let someone else make the further improvements. Why do you insist on everything being done in a single shot?? You earlier complained that nobody had said all problems in a post need be fixed by an edit (misquoting my answer by doing so) yet by deduction that's exactly what you're suggesting here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It was a paraphrase. The exact quote was "This notion that "you must fix most/all of a post's problems, or none at all"

Comment: @Tyler It is not a paraphrase when you've changed the meaning.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Not really; it didn't.

Comment: @Tyler *sigh* Yes, it did. You're fixating on the "fix _all_ problems" issue, so the fact that I said "_most_ or all" is entirely relevant.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you're fixating on a literal interpretation without understanding or appreciating that English is not a strict language, and connotations can be used for referring to "most or all" by "all".

Comment: @Tyler Don't try to defend your blatant misquote. I am capable of looking past the literal but you have been arguing against something I simply didn't say, for the past hour. The difference between "more" and "all" is key to this *entire* question so you can't just shrug it off. In any case, since you can't seem to grasp what my answer says, this conversation appears to be unconstructive and deteriorating quickly. Therefore I propose we shelve it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If you're fixating on whether I refer to "all" or "most" (not "more"; you are misquoting yourself, and yet you're angry with me?!), then you're missing the point. I'm not defending a misquote, I'm trying to enlighten you on what I meant, since it wasn't specified (I didn't say "and I quote", did I?). You don't seem to be able to accept that, which indicates a deeper comprehension problem. The difference between "most" (again, not "more", as you just misquoted), and "all" is actually completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Tyler Well, no, if you can't see the difference between those words in this context then the miscomprehension is certainly not mine.

Comment: So if I wrote a script that found posts that contained 'Thank you' at the bottom, generated the edit, tossed up the result on my screen for me to say "looks good", shared it with 1000 other people, and 30,000 suggested "Thank you" removed edits with 97% accuracy (some misclicks, after all) appeared in the review queue, that would be a net positive?  Just checking the courage of your convictions.  Then add some more scripts for other similar changes...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I certainly can and do understand the difference between those words in any context. I also understand that the point of my comments is not the difference between those words; the point remains the same no matter which word you use (most, all, *or* more as you added later). So the failure to comprehend fully the point of my comments *is* yours.

Comment: @Tyler You're arguing against my point and my point hinges on those words so you've failed comprehension at the first gate!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Those **words** (the fact that there is a plurality is important) offer a range of responses and values, since most !== all (and more !== most and also !== all), I can respond to your use as if you said "all" or if you said "most", and still accurately address your point.

Comment: @Tyler Neither of us has addressed the point in quite some time.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This is a meta site after all, is it not?

Comment: @Tyler We're more like metameta now :p

Comment: I think an important point to some of the arguments I've seen in this set of comments is that sometimes, people aren't good with grammar. Editors included. Or people can look over things, even "obvious and horrible spelling/grammar errors" in a post. Looking at it that way, if the edit fixes anything on a salvageable post, it's not too minor. If the editor is a non-native speaker that understands a little of the grammar rules, and also knows fluff should be removed, but they miss "huge" grammar/spelling errors, should they be "punished" for not being a native speaker? Nope.

Comment: @TylerH: If a post contains an obvious flaw, then until such time as a fix is accepted, people are likely to try to fix it, and each such attempt will waste moderator time.  If the person who fixed it doesn't deserve rep for doing so, the proper state of the system should be "post gets fixed; fixer's rep remains unchanged".  The fact that the person who suggested the edit doesn't deserve rep doesn't imply the post should remain as it was.

Answer (score 6):

### tl;dr

Today my opinion on this subject has completely flipped and I think this is a good change. The "too minor" reason was addressing a problem that didn't really exist.

### Longer version

I used to be in favour of rejecting minor edits, because it grated me that people didn't fix glaring issues with the post. It also annoyed me that they were "rep hunting". However, when I analysed the common objections to this habit I struggled to find anything substantial:

> Trivial edits waste reviewers' time

Perhaps I'm missing something, but the edit review queue is nearly always empty. Presumably feeding on that queue are people intent on doing good and/or earning reviewer badges. It doesn't seem like there's a problem here.

> They are just hunting the +2 rep

This used to bother me, but I've decided I might just be happier *if I don't care*. If someone really wants to get to 1000 reputation by doing minor edits, then I just feel sorry for them. They'll need an additional 1000 "normal" reputation before they are free to edit on their own.

> They fix the trivial stuff and miss the big obvious problem

Yes, that's annoying. And yes, that's not how *I* would edit. But it doesn't prevent someone doing a better job later.

> Without the "too minor" reason, the robo-reviewers will just get worse

Well... part of the reason we don't like those robo-reviewers is because they approved trivial edits rather than rejecting them as "too minor". But asides from this, robo reviewers are idiots who are just going to annoy us whatever the edit system looks like. Some people just want shiny badges whatever the cost and this change will not affect that. If anything, this change ensures a higher percentage of what they approve should have been approved anyway (since most trivial edits are good IME).

### Finally..

I expect this post to attract down-votes. Hopefully some up-votes too. But it would be nice if the comments could articulate *why* something is a problem. Perhaps by pointing out some flaws in my reasoning above.

Comment: It did address some edits but not as much as it seems some people say. I see plenty of edits that focus on one problem (from the same user in a short period of time) and doesn't correct other more or less obvious things that need improvement. I used "Too minor" when I saw a pattern from a user that I had to improve all their edits... wasting my time. So I rejected the worst of them that I saw with "Too minor" and tried to tell the user to improve their edits.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Do you see a downside to approving such edits, now that "too minor" is not an available reason? It seems to me like it cost you a lot of time to enforce the "too minor" rule.

Comment: Yes as the editor will never improve his edits to the point the reviewers won't ask themselves "Should I improve it or just accept... or reject as invalid?". When I ask myself that question for edits of the same user, "Too minor" was an appropriate reject reason.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau But now the question is merely "is the edit invalid or not". That's a much quicker decision. Reviewers can choose to edit further if they wish, but that has always been the case.

Comment: I think you've yet to discover a discreet charm of _[Reject and Edit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/227991/165773)_ when reviewing suggestions that fix the trivial stuff and miss the big obvious problem. _That_ was what helped me most in adopting to disappearance of too minor reason. While in the past, _too minor_ led me to essentially leaving the post as is (including that "big obvious problem"), I am now really motivated to improve. It of course helps that since end August, [robo approvers can't break my flow anymore](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270498/839601)

Comment: @gnat In your view, what is wrong with those minor edits? I'm assuming here that you are talking about trivial but valid edits.

Comment: @Duncan wrong is when, as you described, these miss big obvious problem - that's when I hit Reject and Improve and fix that big obvious problem... and I love it (when I can't see what else to improve, things get bit more complicated, and I put effort to decide whether to approve or reject with custom message, but this eventually turned out not really annoying)

Comment: @gnat I'm specifically asking what problem it causes when they only edit part of the post and miss the big issue? Sure it's annoying, but is it anything more than that?

Comment: indiscriminate approval leaves suggestors oblivious about substantial improvements they could have done. Too minor tried to address this, but I like current system better (possibly because I myself learned to edit from my rejected suggestions), current system forces me to show what suggestor missed - either with my own edit, or with custom rejection message

Comment: @gnat While I sometime use the custom message, using "Too minor" was faster... I can also put "Too minor" in a custom message but I feel removing "Too minor" wasn't necessary in the first place, it should have been revamped to be more specific on "This edit does not add a proper amount of value to be worth the time it takes to review." or a better worded version of what I've come up with. I can live with the current ways but it's a bit more tedious on some cases.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau as someone who was once upon a time at "receiving end" of too-minor rejections, I can tell you that while being faster for single review, it was likely not faster in the long run. It took me quite a bunch of rejections to figure what I am doing wrong - and in the meantime, I was still wasting other reviewers time with low quality edits. Nowadays, system forces me to reject stuff so that suggestor learns to make good edits faster (so that they start making good edits sooner and this saves time of reviewers who can just hit approve)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Because XKCD is *always* relevant]

Here:

[Approve as too minor](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149722/approve-as-too-minor/238039#238039)

Shog had a discussion some days ago, and people seems to agree that too minor has to go. This is evident that goes hand by hand with the "Reject and edit" button. If you consider a edit "too minor" you should fix the issues that weren't fixed in the original edit.

Comment: +1 and the edits that are too minor to the extent that they are just pointless can be addressed in the custom bar.

Comment: Ugh.  Most of the edits I reject as too minor are indeed pointless, and don't require "proper" fixing, just proper rejection.

Comment: @Xander you are beating the messenger.

Comment: That's not my intention, my intention is only to express my displeasure with the message.  :-)

Comment: @Xander There's still the custom rejection reason if you are really that committed to rejecting the edit.

Comment: perfect. now there's no built-in reason to reject those edit-repo-scrappers

Comment: @AirThomas Yes, but there are way too many edits that are legitimately too minor, and not having a dedicated reject reason means even more reviewers will cop out and and auto-approve, (we have enough of these already)  and we'll be left with front pages full of garbage edits after some new user decides he's going to spell-check his way to a badge.

Comment: "If you consider a edit "too minor" you should fix the issues that weren't fixed in the original edit." Yes, yet another reason to keep your fingers away from review queues. We should probably get rid of all the approve/vote stuff and require everyone to fix the things that would have lead them to not approving or wanting to close/delete something. That will get us much better content (from the three people that then will still do something)

Comment: @PlasmaHH I'm ROFL. Let's just remove the close button, because users should improve a question instead of closing/deleting it? ;)

Comment: @Xander An edit that fixes spelling is not "garbage"! What's wrong with you?! This feels like a vendetta/crusade. Jealous of those with time to spare correcting spelling?

Comment: @Theolodis: why not? if we say "hey, dont reject edits, improve them always" we can also go that route and say "hey, dont reject questiosn, improve them always".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, that are wrong.  When the front page of an SE site is suddenly filled with two and three year old questions with accepted answers because someone has gone through and made insignificant spelling corrections, those are indeed garbage edits with net negative value for the site as a whole.

Comment: @Xander I really don't see how this is a problem. If you hate it so much, change your front page from "active" to "new" view.

Comment: I agree with @Lightness. You have features available to you to customize your experience; use them. If front-page bumps from minor edits are causing you that much distress, *make a feature request about what gets bumped to the front page*.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So your response to "users are spamming garbage content on the site" is "stop looking at everything and you won't see any of the garbage".  That's not a solution, it's creating an even worse problem.  Making the "active" view unusable by flooding the site with tons of trivial edits means that *real* edits won't actually generate the attention that they deserve, bad edits won't have an opportunity to be caught, etc.  Destroying (for any practical sense) the "active" page just so people can farm rep doing nothing is *actively harmful*.

Comment: @Servy: Wtf? No, I'm talking about valid edits, regardless of their quantity (which is completely irrelevant). If the edits are "garbage" ie actually _wrong_, reject as invalid. As for the rest of your comment I shan't respond because you're talking about something totally different, it seems. I use the "active" page and there is _no_ "spamming", " flooding", "destroying" problem. It's in your head.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sure, it's not flooded with crap now.  What do you think will happen when you go around telling people that *edits that add zero value are now entirely appropriate, and we'll give you 2 rep for performing edits that make no meaningful change*.  It will *result* in the active view *becoming* flooded with crap, making it unusable. Because now you're changing your position from "it doesn't matter if we encourage people to make pointless edits, you can just ignore them by not using the active view" to "we can encourage people to make pointless edits and nothing will change".

Comment: @Servy Who's saying that edits with zero value are now appropriate?? And when has my position had _anything_ to do with "pointless" edits? (hint: never) We're discussing minor edits that improve a post to some degree, without necessarily fixing a majority of its problems.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [You are](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270961/disappearance-of-too-minor-where-is-the-relevant-discussion/270971#comment92582_270971) in your assertion that the entire *idea* of "too minor" is an invalid reason for rejecting an edit in the first place.  "too minor", if you actually read its definition, has nothing to do with the percentage of the problems it fixes, it has everything to do with the amount of value added.  An edit is "too minor" if making it isn't adding a lot of value, that's it.

Comment: @Servy My point is that _any_ edit that improves a post, be it through a spelling correction or formatting change, is an improvement. Rejecting such an edit just because the editor _could_ have gone further is completely insane, but it seems to be the popular move. Seemingly in order to "punish" those editors and stop them from gaining rep. I don't get it at all. Sure, if there's literally no improvement, then it's simply an "invalid edit". Again this seems really obvious to me but maybe that's just because I am a native speaker.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit As I very specifically went out of my way to say, it has *nothing* to do with whether or not they could have gone further.  That has zero bearing on whether a post is "too minor, given its definition.  It's purely a question of whether the edit is adding sufficient value.  Edits have costs; non-zero costs.  A suggestion that adds an entirely negligible amount of value has all of those same costs, thus encouraging edits of minuscule value are a *net negative* on the site.  An edit needs to be of greater value than the costs it creates to have a net positive effect.

Comment: @Servy The costs are utterly miniscule. If reviewing or reading the active view are strenuous for you, just don't do it, because most people manage just fine. The cost is _minimal_, and the benefit of _any_ post improvement is high. At thi point it sounds like cost-benefit analysis driven by a least-effort approach to SO usage. Not a great way to improve the network.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Making the "active" view useless is a **HUGE** cost.  If droves of minor edits drive a large number of people to stop using that view it will have *major* detrimental effects to the site.  If all of the good reviewers stop reviewing suggested edits because they see nothing but minor edits adding no value then that too, is a *huge* problem that will end up manifesting itself in lots of ways.  The fact that you don't value your time at all, and consider wasting it to have no cost, doesn't mean that nobody else values their time.

Comment: @Servy lol "useless" _hardly_. I actually like to be able to review new edits. It's a GOOD thing, especially as so many editors are getting it so wrong. ;) But I'm not going to continue this discussion because your notion that I "don't value my time" is ludicrous and shows you're more interested in forming strawman arguments and being borderline offensive than actually discussing this!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I agree, it's not useless, and so many editors do get it wrong, but if the entire "active" view gets flooded with 95% minor edits adding no value then finding the actual meaningful changes among them becomes *much* harder.  It results in either wasting a ton of many people's time, people no longer using the "active" view out of frustration, or people not noticing the actual important activity (at least as often).  All of which are costs, certainly much greater than a bunch of edits with a negligible change in the value of a post.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit So if you *do* actually value your time then why are you asserting that making edits with virtually no change in the value of a post, but resulting in consuming the time of a number of active users of the site as not even being worth considering?  Are you saying that you value your time but you don't value the time of anyone else on the site?

Comment: @Servy No, we are disagreeing on "virtually no change". You are sort of stuck in your own ways on this one, as evidenced by your odd conclusion that I must not care about anyone's time. Anyway my view is clearly laid out in my answer so perhaps we'd best leave it at that; I'm evidently failing at educating you (:P) whilst commenting on mobile in the sun.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How do you disginguish, "virtually no change" from ["A tiny improvement ... however extensively"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270961/disappearance-of-too-minor-where-is-the-relevant-discussion/270962?noredirect=1#comment92117_270974).  That says pretty unambiguously that it doesn't matter how little an edit changes, to you no change in value is too small.

Comment: @Servy No positive change, no. I don't dispute that genuinely valueless edits should be rejected but I think we disagree on where that threshold lies. I've gotta be honest though I'm caring less and less as this debacle progresses :p

Comment: Mmm... can you guys discuss this in, dunno, chat? I was scared when I checked my inbox (not that I'm against about you two fleshing out your ideas, just that... well.)

Comment: @Braiam: I don't see why. This meta question was posted to obtain opinions. Well, here they are. Hiding them away in some chat that no-one else will ever see is completely pointless. That being said, we're done here because it appears impossible to actually discuss anything with Servy.

Comment: Sometimes I wish there was someone round here who actually knew the rules, and could be considered "right", rather than discussions over and over. That said, I'm with @Servy on almost everything said here (from my past experience on meta, that means Servy is probably wrong)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit If you create a chat room and link to it, the record of that conversation should remain indefinitely [provided you post at least 15 messages](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#retention). So the debate is not lost, it just doesn't drown out other voices.