# My edit was rejected because it "changed the original meaning or intent", but I was just reinforcing changes already made

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I hope this link works, but here's the edit in question:
https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5691801

All I did was move the OP's "Update" to the top and added a strikethrough to his original answer, since it appears he changed his answer. I thought it was important to clarify that the original answer was not entirely correct and that the update should be understood as the answer.

I'm not taking this personally or anything, I just want to know the reasoning behind how my edit was so different from the OP's edit, which I was trying to reinforce/clarify.

Thanks!

Comment: Ironically, "too minor" is [no longer one of the canned rejection reasons that we can choose from](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270961/disappearance-of-too-minor-where-is-the-relevant-discussion).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The review consensus was *"This edit is too minor; suggested edits should be substantive improvements addressing multiple issues in the post."*

In general, answers should be *a coherent whole;* that is, the answer should *incorporate any edits naturally.*  Sectioning off answers into separate sections by using devices such as "EDIT," "UPDATE" and "Original Answer" is not ideal, and there's an edit history anyway, if people want to see a rundown of the changes.

Adding strikeout text is especially distracting.  Devices like "UPDATE" and strikeout text should be considered "special effects," used sparingly for special occasions, but not a best practice.  There's a reason why BLINK and MARQUEE are now universally despised.

Comment: I've edited the answer in question to be in line with these practices, to see an example of how to apply them.

Comment: Thanks Robert! I was going to do what @Servy did in his edit, but I was timid about deleting something from such a highly rated answer. I'll be more bold and just delete the irrelevant info next time. :)