# Are there "best practices" on how to review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I'm doing reviews to the best of my knowledge. Yet, every now and then I don't know what I should do with a review. I skip those, but I've been looking around for "best practices" which I couldn't find.

For example: a proposed edit fixing only a typo: the typo should be fixed; but is this the real purpose of "proposing an edit"?

For example, someone types "fix my ocde" and someone proposes an edit to "fix my code".

1. Approve or reject
2. Should I reject and then edit myself just to discourage "reputation hunters"

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6196990

Comment: IMHO, an improvement is an improvement. Fixing only a typo and nothing else without having [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) might be considerred noise tho. I would only reject it and consider it harmful if other obvious improvements to the post weren't done. [This meta Q/A](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/155961/390859) might be related

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are some reviewing "best practices" posted on the main Meta SE site at [What are the guidelines for reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538/what-are-the-guidelines-for-reviewing)

Specifically for the kinds of cases that you're talking about, those edits should be rejected. If the *only* thing wrong with a post is a typo, then someone with full edit privileges can fix it. I can see other things that need to be fixed in the post you linked to (remove "Hi" and capitalize "i"), so that edit should definitely have been rejected (using the Reject and Edit button). If you're going to put something up for review, fix everything that needs fixed at once. That way you don't waste reviewers' time with a series of very minor edits to the same post.

Comment: I would suggest such "best practices" be shown to a user once he "unlocks" a certain review queue...

Comment: @ChrisMaes Yeah, that's not a bad idea. The first place I looked was in the sidebar of the review queue page itself, so that's probably where this kind of information should go.

Comment: I've been looking around on the help page as well... nothing :)

Comment: But "too minor" disappeared... Now we just have "no improvement whatsoever", which doesn't convey quite the same message.

Comment: @Scimonster Oh, you're right. When did that happen? Regardless of when, I'll update my answer.

Comment: @BilltheLizard http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270961/disappearance-of-too-minor-where-is-the-relevant-discussion

Comment: "Those edits should be rejected" - I'd agree with you here, but sadly Shog9 doesn't. He proposes that instead of rejecting as too minor one should now use "reject and edit" - which of course is a total waste of time for everybody involved if the question should be closed instead of edited.

Comment: @l4mpi If the question should be closed, close it. If it needs to be edited, edit it. Either way, the too minor edit should be rejected.

Comment: This notion of "too minor" edits has never made sense to me.  If my question has a tyop, we should leave it in there?  Really?  Why not just fix it?

Comment: @Brian Because there were a lot of other things that needed to be fixed, like I already said. I also already said that if there's *only one* typo, someone can go ahead and fix it, so I'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Sorry, I missed that in my first reading.  :(