# I started avoiding big tags on my questions, is that ok?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits, asking-questions

Big tags like C++, Java and JavaScript (I apologize to other big tags for mentioning them) seem to be so overwhelmed by both garbage and tangential questions.

So to help followers and only attract people who know my problem, I started to omit those tags unless I'm asking specifically about some language feature.

So for example I no longer tag JavaScript for Node.js questions and I no longer tag C++ for Qt framework questions. Should a high rep user re-tag my question and add the tag, I wouldn't roll back. Should a low rep user suggest such edit, I'd reject it as "doesn't substantially improve the post".

Is that attitude ok?

Comment: My only problem is with editing. It doesn't matter if the editor is high or low rep, it still 'doesn't substantially improve the post'

Comment: @AndrewL. I was thinking that rolling back just creates even more unnecesary hassle. I'm not sure if rollback un-bumps the post.

Comment: Yeah, sure.  They are pretty big tags too so you'll get enough views.  Just less of them, you'll have to deal with less junky answers.

Comment: While the Java tag certainly has a lot of junky questions in it, is having the Java tag on a question attracting junky answers? Leaving it off would really only help if a lot of people are looking for questions to answer that don't have that tag. That very well may be the case, but I'd like to see what kind of overlap there is in people following different tag-subtag groups.

Comment: I find it's ok as long as the it doesn't harm the searchability and readability. (a) If a framework/library is only to be used with a specific language, then this language may be omitted, because the language tag wouldn't improve the search results when looking for duplicates. (b) If the framework/library doesn't have associated syntax highlighting, you should provide appropriate hints for syntax highlighting.

Comment: something to think about: our profiles count or answers/questions per given tag. additionally, some badges are received on a tag-specific basis

Comment: @jeremy yeah, [Jon Skeet has a gold android tag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/178/android?userid=22656).

Comment: It'll probably save you from being killed to death.

Comment: I am a high rep user and watch only big tags. I do not notice other questions.

Comment: @Braiam: with 10000 answers in Java that's not a coincidence

Comment: @Thomas which tells you that sometimes, there are certain tags that doesn't matter at all.

Comment: What jeremy said. As well as the outright garbage & tangential questions, there's also the issue of dupes. Presumably, you'd like it if there were more gold badge holders to hammer those dupes. So please don't make it harder than it already is to get gold tag badges.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

There is no real benefit in avoiding popular language tags. You aren't helping people to find your question, you're just making it more difficult.

As long as you *also* tag with the specific tags, such as [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) or [node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node.js), experts in those subjects will filter their searches based on those tags, causing your questions to appear immediately. There is no noise of general [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) questions unless you *want* to see all of that noise.

I don't really buy the argument about only attracting people who know your problem. This seems to assume, as Bill the Lizard pointed out, that it is the tags themselves that are the cause of low-quality content. This is not true. Rather, there is a lot of low-quality content on Stack Overflow, and since these popular tags are…well, popular, they are home to a lot of this content.

The only reason why this would be a problem is if you were trying to read *all* questions tagged [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) or [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). To my knowledge, no one is able to do this, any more than they can drink from a firehose. Most people just filter on more narrow tags like you describe. Or they sample a smattering of random questions from the "big tags" each time they visit the site.

Consider the case where I know about Qt, and want to answer questions about it, but I'm most comfortable with the C++ language. Qt has Python bindings, but I don't know anything about Python, so I don't want to worry about those questions. Therefore, I filter all the questions about both [qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/qt) and [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) based on their tags. If your question doesn't have the latter tag, I won't find it. Oops!

> Should a low rep user suggest such edit, I'd reject it as "doesn't substantially improve the post".

Well, yeah. That's reasonable. It is *not* a substantial improvement. But if it were part of an edit that *did* substantially improve the post, then you should approve it.

Comment: You made a good point. This is why I asked before fully adopting my new strategy. Now I see it's useless if not harmful. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

I don't see what harm could adding a big tag to your question do, unless you already have five (the limit) other relevant tags.

It only brings more attention to your question, which means more answers. If you get bad answers, you can downvote them (and if appropriate, flag as VLQ/NAA). IMO it's better to get five bad answers and one good answer, than no answers at all.

Regarding edits: I think you shouldn't judge (suggested) edits based on the reputation of the person who makes them. If the edit improves your question in *any* way, approve it. Also, note that ["too minor" rejection reason was removed intentionally](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/270961/3853934) (see also [“Too minor” edits - better to leave poor quality on the site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253326/3853934)).

Comment: Isn't the actual programming language used relevant enough to *never* leave out? Like, when going to a car mechanic and complaining that the airco doesn't work, your spare tyre is flat, the front lights are out, your wind screen is busted, and there is this weird sound when changing gears – that's 5, and so you don't mention you crashed the car into a wall.

Comment: @RadLexus but each needs an specialized mechanic to fix... unless you are into garage mech.

Answer (score -5):

> So to help followers and **only attract people who know my problem**, I started to omit those tags **unless I'm asking specifically about some language feature.**

That's good. You only want to attract those that are able to answer your question, not just exposure for the sake of it. That keeps the SNR up for everyone. You as asker and them as answerers. If you aren't asking about the features of the language, I don't see any problem to not using language tags or just focusing on the really relevant tags.

You've seen a benefit of doing so, if not, you would have stopped without asking this question.

Comment: Fully agreed. Casting the net too wide just vastly increases the probability that you get off-topic / alternative suggestion answers. *"I don't know what Node.js is but with JQuery you do it like this."*

Comment: @Gimby you should totally stop that and try jQuery

Comment: I do! I use it happily in browser-side Javascript code served up through a Node.JS HTTP server :)