# Are you told when you are banned from reviewing?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, review-suspension, banning

Every so often you'll get tested in the review queue, and if you fail you're told so.

If you fail enough, do you get "banned"? If you are banned, what happens? Are you told or just given a hellban where you just don't get to do review queues?

How long do bans last?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you fail enough reviews, you'll receive a *temporary* review ban. You'll see an error message when you try to review more:

> You have made too many incorrect reviews.

The message may include more details as to why you were banned.

Review bans can last up to 30 days, depending on previous bans; if you haven't learned from a shorter ban a longer ban can be applied. Moderators can also apply review bans, manually.

See [Review ban progressive system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256231).

Comment: Ok, I was just wondering because whenever I look in the queues there's a number, but when I click the link it's empty. I thought I'd been hell banned because I failed a review.

But looking around meta it seems that it's because the queues get cleared so quickly that the number is usually not accurate (as people have already cleared the queue before one gets there) :)

Comment: @PeterSouter Hellbans *don't exist* (as per the tag-wiki description for it: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hellban). Queues certainly are cleared pretty quickly; on the Review page I sometimes see '30 posts' for the New Posts queue, but when I try to review it says the queue has been cleared.

Comment: @PeterSouter: yes, the queues are cleared at a fair clip; to make the review counters work on the scale of Stack Overflow, some pretty hefty caching is involved. So you are not review-banned, there is no such thing as a hell-ban on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @PeterSouter: [This is what is happening to you.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276031/review-cache-indicator-timer)

Comment: I feel like I'm running into a test every couple of reviews at the moment. Is this even possible?

Comment: @Totem: it depends on your success rate, see [Stop bothering me with suggested edit review audits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/182722)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I  see. I haven't ever been notified of failing a test, and have only been notified a few times about passing one. So perhaps these haven't really been tests, but frightfully bad edits/posts. Sorry, I should have emphasised that I FEEL like i'm running into them a lot. Maybe I'm getting paranoid :s

Comment: @Totem: you've passed all of 2 audits in the past 24 hours.

Answer (score 9):

***Yes, it is possible to be temporarily banned for too many incorrect reviews.*** The ban can vary, depending on how many *bad* reviews you made.
The system exists in order to ensure you are paying attention, mostly because reviewing content incorrectly can have an adverse effect on the community.

You will receive this message:

> You have made too many incorrect reviews. For an example of a task you
>   should have reviewed differently, see:
>   https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5234487

From [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262812/request-information-on-you-have-made-too-many-incorrect-reviews) (***Martijn Pieters's answer***):

> On the whole your reviewing patterns come over as a Robo reviewer; you
>   are not paying enough attention and are approving even minor edits too
>   easily, but you are paying just enough attention to not be fooled by
>   audits. As such I think a moderator gave you a manual review ban.
>
> Please be more selective in what small edits you approve.

Comment: Uh, I find it a good thing to aprove minor edits. Each spellfix or formatting which is fixed improves the site.

Comment: @eckes: the main issue was not minor edits in general, but people fixing a tiny problem but not fixing other obvious issues, which wastes more time than what it would have taken in the first place had one person fixed as many obvious issues as possible.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy no reason to ban somebody for actually reducing the edit backlog. It is certainly better to accept valid spelling fixes than to reject them.