# No available reviews - But the recent reviews keeps piling up

Tags: discussion, review-queues

I've been visiting the Review a couple of times each day, but i've yet to do a single review since there are no reviews available.

Yet the recent reviews-list is constantly updating itself with new completed reviews from other users.

At this point i've shamefully refreshed the site to see if any available reviews would show up.

They dont, but the the recent reviews-list keeps updating with completed reviews for those queues.

Is there some kind of trick to it or do I just have to be super lucky to get a review going?

Comment: Reviews go very, very fast. You need to be lucky.

Comment: If it helps: you are not alone in wondering if you'll catch any reviews; [this user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277980/are-you-told-when-you-are-banned-from-reviewing) worried they might've been banned from reviewing without being told.

Comment: Happens to everybody. No one can see reviews, the queue is always empty. The reviews go very fast, it's just a matter of luck.

Comment: To get reviews, I created bookmarks (one for first posts, one for late answers) and I click on them like a maniac until I get something

Comment: The counts on the main review page that lists all the review queues are not accurate at all. You can often click on one of the queues if it shows that there are 0 available, and get a whole bunch of reviews.

Comment: I just had a very short test and think there might be an issue here. For the suggested edits it seemed that once I was in the system and reviewing them there always was another one available to review that I moved onto after clicking one of the action buttons but meanwhile the main page was always reporting "0" whenever I refreshed it. Caching?

Comment: @MartinSmith Almost certainly. A huge, huge number of users see that number every time they load almost any page on SO. The queue page itself gets much less traffic and can probably afford a more lenient cache.

Comment: In the past, review queue counts were loaded live. However, someone DDoS'd this and caused the review page to stop working. Caching was implemented to combat this, but it has a drawback: sometimes the page has stale numbers. In other words, sometimes it says that there are 0 reviews when there are in fact some, and in other cases it says that there are available reviews when there are in fact none.