# What to do when a tiny edit would markedly improve the post?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36420066/2209946) is of good quality, but the submitter only inserted one newline instead of two before a code block (item 3), which makes a big difference to its readability.

The edit form won't let me submit a one-character change. It suggests editing another part of the post, but there's nothing I could improve.

What's the Stack Overflow way to handle this?

Comment: Seems to be an [ongoing holy war](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252249/2209946). I'm picking up my spear in favour of minor edits.

Comment: I believe the original rationale of not allowing too minor edits was (at least in part) that if a post was edited too many times or by too many editors it would automatically become community wiki, which has a number of consequences such making the original author loose reputation earnings from it.  However since 2014 this is no more the case.

Comment: Don't think that was the original rationale, @Bakuriu. If it were, we would prevent such edits from trusted users, too. This applies only to users who are *suggesting* edits, and the reason is because a suggested edit requires review by at least 3 trusted members of the community. It consumes their time and energy, which they could be investing in other ways to clean up the site. More bang for the buck and all that. Certainly there are edge cases where < 6 characters can deliver a lot of bang, but it is not common. And there is almost always something else you can fix too, while you're at it.

Comment: I would say that the majority of the too minor / not too minor wars hinge more upon edits like fixing small typos and not fixing capitalization (or something of the like), rather than absolutely clear-cut formatting problems like this.  Also, I don't buy that there was nothing else to fix in this particular post - I can see *plenty* of other things to fix, which Magisch did.  The cases in which a single character is truly the *only* thing to fix are, I assert, so rare that we shouldn't be bothered by them.

Comment: There have been edits to the answer now, and it's probably better with them. I'm a relatively infrequent user of the site and wouldn't feel comfortable making this magnitude of change - or putting in the time to ensure its quality - when the 'right' thing feels to be simply fixing the formatting issue. Requiring substantial edits reduces the frequency at which these problems are fixed, as they must be done by someone with more dedication than a drive-by "I'm working, but hmm, this needs a newline".

Comment: @David: my view is that small edits are much more acceptable once a user's edits no longer need to be reviewed. Part of the problem is thought to be disturbing the review queue for lots of trivial items.

Answer (score 25):

In this particular case, I would change the list markers from `3)` to `3.`. This will cause the text to be marked up as a *proper* HTML list.

If you then prefix the code block with *eight* spaces, it will be contained *inside* list item 3 so that it doesn't disrupt the list itself.

**Example:**

3. List item.

   ```
   <p>Some code
   ```

---

This will probably be enough to let you suggest an edit; I have forgotten the exact rules.

Comment: At least 6 characters' difference.

Comment: A hack is to add a <!-- comment -->, this gives enough changed characters.

Comment: @LeifNeland Hacks and attemps to avoid different filters tends to annoy reviewers and make it more likely to reject edit or even flag user.

Comment: Sure, but an edit might be important, and still under the the required length. But then it's perhaps better to not try to be sneaky. A viewable line like "(OP mistakenly wrote a+b instead of a-b)" would allow the edit to go through. It depend on how likely somebody who is able to, will come around to edit in a comment, and how "dangerous" the error is.

Comment: @LeifNeland Seems like a way to circumvent the 2000 edit priviledge to me...

Answer (score 20):

If there are really no other improvements to be made, you could just post a comment. Then either the OP or a high-rep user can make the change.

Comment: Is this a worthy time to flag for moderator intervention?

Comment: @Sam: I wouldn't think so. My understanding is that dealing with individual edits would not be a good use of a moderator's time, unless there's some serious issue involved (which is not the case here).

Comment: Yea, didn't think so either...curious to see what a moderator thinks.

Comment: Do not use mod flags for stuff that the community is perfectly capable of doing.  Comments are fine, but flags definitely aren't @Sam.

Answer (score 2):

Find other edits to do and leave one character edits to higher rep users who don't have to have it go through review.  It is more than annoying to have an unrelated change in order to get over the character limit which the reviewer then has to edit.  This causes more work than it gains.

Answer (score -8):

If there really is only one character change needed that will make a huge difference perhaps adding whitespace characters to fudge the minimum characters is an option as a hack.

Perhaps this is frowned upon though...

Comment: When reviewing, I find it a pain to deal with *"This text added to be allowed an edit"* - it's normally easiest to Reject And Edit, which is probably not what the original editor wanted...

Comment: @TobySpeight: Probably not what the original editor wanted, but it does improve the post, which is more important.