# How do moderators deal with users who are neurodiverse (e.g., have autism, mental problems)?

Tags: discussion, moderation, users, moderators, accessibility

The moment you read this, please be gentle to me. Thank you.

This is my very first question on Meta. I'm feeling very good and scared at the same time. Every second I'm building this question makes me more stressed, due to thinking of the upcoming comments and downvotes.

I do, of course, understand two things:

- Moderators don't know if the person who asked is mentally ill.
- Rules are rules, which also apply to us, treating us as equal (too).

Just like for everybody else, scoldings are part of our growth. But, our problem is that, unlike a normal person who can change and improve easily, we struggle to digest such lectures.

**So, I came here to seek help and ask if you have standards to deal with us, or if you have any suggestions.**

My siblings want me to stop interacting with this community, as it heavily affects me. At the same time, I want to interact with normal people and become used to doing so.

Thank you very much and have a wonderful day.

For any references to my posts, well... they're all bad questions and all have been deleted. I'm sorry.

**Edit:**

I don't know how to react, I don't know which one to accept as an answer, everyone is so nice to me. I wanted to accept all answers and comments but that's not possible, so I upvoted everyone to be fair.

I'm still scared, but I had to respond. Thank you very much for helping me out here; if everyone was like this I feels like I can continue doing this. I'll pause at some point if it's getting worse and then continue again later.

Comment: You got an upvote from me and someone else (at the time of writing), FWIW. If you have trouble understanding rules (or digesting the rules), that's a big problem. I don't want to offend you, but I genuinely think that it's better you follow what your siblings say. If you want to interact with other people, I think there's therapy and other treatments for that. Maybe after the treatment and therapy you could interact better here. (Also I really hope this comment doesn't offend you, I don't mean to offend or alienate you in any way).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144601/323179

Comment: @10Rep Thank you for your kind words.
`Laurel`, thank you for the link of Meta StackExchange.
`cigien`, thank you for correcting my grammar.

Comment: Whether you have mental problems or not doesn't matter at all if that's the case; if we heavily affect you, you should stop interacting with us.

Comment: About what kind of moderators are you talking about? High reputation users with moderating privileges or elected moderators that have diamond ◆  next to their name? People often conflate the two.

Comment: I'm afraid there are a host of sites which will be unfit for you to participate in. I would also treat sites such as Reddit, Twitter and Youtube as read-only sites as the interactions with other users on those sites can be brutal, far more so than on Stack Overflow which has strict rules of conduct and a very dedicated topic which prohibits most subjects that can personally affect people. This is not a Stack Overflow specific thing.

Comment: "I want to interact with normal people and become used to it." Great attitude, don't choose to become a victim for your circumstances. I've done a similar journey. Good look with learning and experimenting with life!

Comment: The comment by Alex just now says the most important point, but I guess that every decent moderator would take extra care to explain all the rules and show understanding when being aware of a user's mental problems. I wonder, if maybe there should be more. If you have suggestions, feel welcome to post them. It's probably useful to get a perspective from someone directly affected.

Comment: (con't) The other problem is that the statistically few who make your life difficult are the ones visible (or at least you see their actions), vs. the many who are nice and helpful.

Comment: If the references can not found, perhaps add some more detailed information to the question?

Comment: The Stack Exchange Network values content more than the well being of its users. So if you're having trouble receiving criticism, following the rules or interacting with folks on the internet, it may be better to take a step back for the moment, because you (sadly) can't expect much help coming from SE

Comment: Your question is an important one, but I fear that you're asking it to the wrong people since your question is in regards to how to approach a site such as this that can affect your mental health, something that few (or none) of us are equipped to answer. I hope that you have a mental health counselor, and if you do, that you address this question and the specifics to this counselor.  I do believe that this site can have a positive effect on you if you have a decent well laid-out plan on how to deal with it and the stress it can bring, and a good counselor can help you with this plan.

Comment: You should be aware that software development is mentally challenging for the following reasons: 1) Uncaring machinery: compilers and linkers don't care about your issues and will emit pages of errors and warnings anyway.  2) Extreme frustration: achieving a successful build is nothing compared with the often depressing, and seemingly endless, loops of test/debug while you try to make the system do what you want. 3)  When you get it do what you want, you will usually find that is not what you required.  4) When you get there, your customer will change the requirements.  Please take care...

Comment: *"every second I'm building this question makes me more stressed due to thinking of the upcoming comments and downvotes*". You are [catastrophising](https://www.healthline.com/health/anxiety/catastrophizing). Take a minute and think about this situation for a while. What's the worst that could happen? You get downvoted, get endless comments and answers, your question gets closed and deleted. So, what? It has nothing to do with you as a person. See how well receive this question is right now!

Comment: @adiga There was this one time I asked a question on a Stack Exchange site after checking if the subject was on topic. Then it got closed as off-topic. The fact that it got closed didn't affect me, but what affected me was the feeling that I was unable to understand something as simple as a meta post that said "these subjects are on topic" (I wasn't helped by some other life trouble), so it made me feel like a failure as a human-being (yeah, it's stupid, I know). It took me a few months to fix stuffs on my end before asking for feedbacks to avoid doing the same mistake again.

Comment: @MartinJames very true, the very nature of the job can be very stressful. In fact when starting out I actually suffered a minor burnout when a little too much responsibility was dropped on my plate the first time, I spent a good three weeks doing little more than sleeping to recover. It takes a while to adjust to having to solve numerous problems with unknown solutions within a strict deadline.

Comment: @Clockwork I get what you mean. It's hard not to take it personally. Especially for neurodiverse people who have an irrational fear of judgement, insecurity and imposter syndrome more than others. The only solution is practice and more practice. Just by observing for a period, you understand what questions are allowed, not allowed, ignoring angry comments, identifying duplicates, how to approach a problem etc.

Comment: Related (cross site): *[How to respond to questions from schizophrenic or pre-schizophrenic people](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11117)*

Comment: @adiga: Yes, lurking for a while may be more effective than reading rules.

Comment: Hi, neurodivergent moderator here. What's up? (I can't commit to this question right this moment or even this weekend, but I thought I'd just touch base.)

Comment: Aren't most people mentally challenged at least, so why should it here be different. It is impossible without knowing TT he exact type of illness someone has to handle him correctly but to be honest a case for your therapist so that you learn to handle this in ypeof situation

Comment: OK, I've been peeking at this thread every now and then while I'm busy, but I wanted to clarify something very important: neurodiversity is *not* mental illness. Autism, ADHD, dyslexia, learning disabilities, etc are neurodevelopmental disabilities, not mental illnesses. Illnesses are generally thought of as things to be cured - but neurodiversity is just that: diversity. It's not inherently bad - what's bad is the suffering that comes with the difficulties associated with it, whether psychosomatic or caused/exacerbated by a world that is designed for NTs (see: social model of disability).

Comment: Other than that, I agree with Clockwork and simbabque. I really like their answers. Really good advice. Perhaps my perspective would be valuable too, if I can get around to sharing it. I feel like I'd have quite a fair bit to say to you. I did write about my experience [previously](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367976/are-we-collectively-wired-to-be-rude/367987#367987), but it might be a little too pessimistic for this question. But give it a read at any rate.

Comment: Shiz, are you familiar with rejection sensitive dysphoria (RSD)? I have that in spades, IRL and elsewhere online. I know what it's like to be criticized even slightly and utterly recoil and lose the ability to function for the rest of the day or week, like it's the end of the world. If anything I'm surprised it hasn't been that much of a problem for me on here in the 10 years I've been active (how I became a mod, I guess). But that's *not* to invalidate your experiences. I can absolutely understand and empathize with how a site like Stack Overflow would affect someone with RSD.

Comment: @adiga: I'd contend that the fear we experience is by and large rational. ND people are greatly misunderstood, and what's irrational is actually much of the criticism and judgement we receive in our day-to-day lives, especially from NTs. (But that's not to say our response to this fear can't be irrational - see my RSD comment above.)

Comment: "But our problem is that, a normal person can change and improve easily, while we struggle to digest their lectures." No, when you tell someone that something they did is wrong, most people just look for an excuse to criticize you and feel good about ignoring their need to improve. Hence the welcoming initiative, which is supposedly based on how unhappy people are at being criticized. I just want to thank you for not rejecting all criticism and actually realizing a need to improve.

Comment: @BoltClock, going way offtopic here, but speaking as someone who is ADHD, (and has C-PTSD and bipolar spectrum depression on top of that), and also happens to be a specialist in neuropsychiatry, I must come and say that all the examples you gave _are_, in fact, mental illnesses. Or more appropriately called "disorders". Not that this matters a whole lot here, just saying.

Comment: @Marc.2377: As far as I'm concerned that's just because their definitions are in the DSM. Certainly disorder is a better word than illness. I don't know if medicine just considers mental, neurological, psychological and psychiatric to all mean the same thing (vs simply greatly overlapping/interacting), but as a professional with lived experience I'm sure you personally try not to conflate them all. You probably understand that calling autism/ADHD a mental illness is stigmatizing both in everyday conversation and in a clinical setting. That's another point I was hoping to make.

Comment: No idea what the context or motivation of this question might be, if any, since I just don't have the time available to devote to this site right now, but... in general, we moderators *don't* deal with people in any different way; we try to treat everyone equally. If you need special consideration/understanding from a diamond moderator who might be "scolding" you, please ask in an appropriate forum. Related: [Does this site value / accommodate contributions of people with disabilities?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342353/)

Comment: @Cody Gray: It would help if you could name an example of an appropriate forum. Perhaps a message to the community team via the contact form?

Comment: Yes, that would be one, @BoltClock. But I feel there are many; too numerous to exhaustively name. Most scoldings worthy of the name occur via moderator messages, so sending a reply to that would be perfectly apt, especially since all such replies are confidential (seen only by other moderators). If the scolding was done more publicly, you could reply asking the mod to open up a private chat, as there's some context you'd like to provide them that you don't feel comfortable sharing in public.

Comment: SO is never about people and posters but only about content. It is archive. Just about every newbie who gets downvotes mistakes these to be critical of him or her. They never are.

Comment: @Shiz - How do you come to think that the people with which you interact here are _normal_? ;-)

Comment: @BoltClock Not to put pressure on you, but I eagerly await your post. What I shared, I did with little to no knowledge on the matter. But I felt like I needed to do it (I had this strange impression that asker was in great pain when I was reading the post). So I'll gladly listen to someone who actually know something.

Comment: I've rolled back the title edit; I find "neurodiversity" way more unclear and unspecific. I do not see a case being made for it, only against.

Comment: @CodeCaster You remind me that when I initially read the original title, I understood it as "for [group A] or [group B]", rather than implying that both are the same, although I don't know which meaning was the intended one.

Comment: **If you have a specific need or requirement** due to neurodiversity or a disability, and this need isn't currently being met, that could perhaps be addressed. But otherwise the idea of being inclusive means treating everyone the same as a rule, in a way that works for the largest number of people, and making exceptions / accommodations (if possible) for anyone who voices a need for those. But (elected) mods mostly use their powers to act on content, not users, i.e. to close or delete stuff - something regular users can largely do as well, just not always as effectively.

Comment: In which way does this site "heavily" affect you? I wouldn't really call the main site a "community" and it's not really "normal" interaction with others (Meta might be more of a community, but probably not the healthiest one). It's a Q&A that's very focused on content. You're probably not going to make any friends, you're often/occasionally/rarely going to get downvoted, people are going to very blunt at times, you could get ignored, people likely aren't going to care about you beyond what you post. All you might learn here is how to express technical ideas well and not take things personally

Comment: 2/2 If you want interaction with others that's not personal and that's technical in nature, then this site might be fine for that. But if you're looking to make friends or have deeper, more personal interactions that are closer to in-person interactions, then I'd probably suggest looking elsewhere. Like maybe a discussion forum, Discord, Facebook group, Reddit or whatever else.

Comment: @CodeCaster: "Neurodiverse" is unspecific, but it is clear. (At least, notwithstanding the "neurodiverse" vs "neurodivergent" debate that happens within the ND community...)

Comment: @NotThatGuy: I agree that it's important to learn not to take things personally, however impersonal interactions can still affect a person - after all, the ones casting votes and leaving blunt answers are also human, and therefore the interactions often have a human element to them. Not every comment we post or action we take is completely dispassionate.

Comment: Just to chime in: I am also a ND moderator (ADHD, and various mental health issues that are the result of not knowing I had ADHD for most of my adult life). I’m sorry that I don’t have much time to say anything more than this comment, but I wanted to let you know that you are not alone and moderators by and large are aware that we are dealing with people, not machines! :-)

Comment: "*unlike a normal person who can change and improve easily*" hehe, you don't spend much time here do you? Most new users are persistently terrible at adapting their behaviour in line with the site's rules.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with it! We're glad that you feel encouraged by the responses here. I can't emphasize enough that, if you encounter a problem while using the site, look for the flag icon or link-text. That will give you the option to flag for moderator attention. We can't promise fast response times (Stack Overflow is a huge site), but we *do* care, and we take each and every flag seriously. If anyone is not treating you with respect, or there's anything we can do to help you, please let us know.

Comment: *we are dealing with people, not machines!* says our beloved, much appreciated and awesome flag-handling machine @MartijnPieters ... ;)

Comment: The general idea is that nobody should care about _who_ posted something but _what_ the post contains. Ideally, votes should be cast based on content and everyone will be held to the same standard. We don't (shouldn't) care if someone is a newbie, or a veteran, or neurodiverse, or what pronouns they have etc etc. So we won't treat you any differently than anyone else - the site is equally (un)welcoming to everyone :)

Answer (score 71):

While this doesn't answer your question, I'd like to point a few things out.

First, I think it's very brave of you to ask this question.

Second, a disclaimer. I don't know what you are feeling, or how you perceive yourself. Only you know this, and nobody can tell you who you are. I am not trying to tell you what to think about yourself, but rather I am trying to make you aware of how there are different points of view that you might not yet have considered, and might find insightful.

It's unusual to see someone who is *[neurodiverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurodiversity)* use terms such as *mentally ill* or *normal*. Most of the time, it's the [*neurotypical*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurotypical) ("normal" as in, most) people who say that.

A lot of ND people on the internet are very vocal about this distinction, and there are many people who are like you. Anxiety is a real thing. You might want to look at resources such as http://www.autismtoolbox.co.uk/what-does-neurodiversity-mean, and organisations and charities in your country that deal with Autism and other neurodiverse issues to get support, and find like-minded individuals to help you deal with challenges such as the ones you describe.

Many users here on Stack Exchange are ND. Quite a few speak about it openly. Look for their content, and see how they deal with criticism.

Try to distance yourself as a person from the words you write. People here almost never attack a person, they usually just have an opinion on what is being said. It's about providing the right information, not about hurting anyone.

When I edit a question or an answer, or when I cast a close vote, I do this with a view of how the other people might later benefit from the information provided in that question. Much of software development is an iterative process, and so is a lot of the content on this network. You don't own the questions or answers as much as you would in a more traditional forum or mailing list. It's more that you asked it first, and then it's there forever, to not only help you, but for others later (where others include future you, or at least that happens to me occasionally).

So if someone edits your question to fix broken indentation, or to change typos, that's actually them doing you a favour, because it increases your chance of getting a good answer, as well as helping people in the future find the question and answers more easily, therefore getting the help they are looking for.

Equally if someone votes to close, that is very rarely out of spite, but mostly because people who do that care deeply about the quality on the site. This is one of the most common reasons new users get confused, or become sad and discouraged. Many tech people care about quality quite deeply, and they care about the things they work with. I for example always change *PERL* to *Perl* in questions, [because the spelling *PERL* is wrong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl#Name). I do this because I care about this technology, because I've invested a good part of my life into it, and because I would like people who ask questions about it to get a good experience. So I fix their mistake for them, and I tell them. The best way to learn is by making mistakes. There is no malicious intent. I'm trying to be helpful, and to leave respectful comments to point this out.

This explanation might help you see other people's actions in a different light. Most users here that invest time to write answers and curate the site do this because they love helping others and because they care about the technology. Some of them are not as good at being kind in a neurotypical way as others. For them, showing kindness means making you don't make mistakes, but they might not have the same skills to consider your feelings as others do. Stack Overflow is doing a few things to improve this experience for new users<sup>1</sup>, but that's a work in progress, and it's very hard to please everyone.

I hope this helps you look at it in a way that feels more comfortable to you, and you can make SO work for you. Good luck!

---

<sup>1) I'm not very good at following these as my niche on here is rather small and we don't get it as much as other language tags, so CITATION needed</sup>

Comment: I'd like to believe that people who got persecuted a lot eventually believe that they're the problem. A bit like how my wife was persecuted because of her wheelchair. It's only when she became an adult that she realised it.

Comment: I think I like your answer. It's like a more indepth version of what I tried to write as someone who barely participate on SO.

Comment: @Clockwork thank you. I've upvoted yours, I think you make a good point too.

Comment: @Clockwork: Yep, we internalize it and then we have to work to unlearn it, otherwise we risk perpetuating harm to ourselves and *others* as a consequence of this. It's messed up that we end up having to take some responsibility for something that never was our fault to begin with.

Comment: The clocks are having a spell here.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Like clockwork!

Comment: @Clockwork What you describe sounds like should be described as gaslighting (e.g. person A causing a problem for person B, and then person A accuses person B of being the one to cause the problem). Not arguing or anything, just remarking.

Comment: @TylerH I actually forgot about that word, but yeah, it's rather close to it, although I think in case of gaslighting, people usually know they're knowingly lying themselves. Meanwhile, from what little I know, sometimes discriminiation and such have people believing what they think is "normality" and enforcing it. Edit: Actually, I forgot to mention "sometimes", as it's not always motivated the same way depending on different individuals.

Comment: @Clockwork I actually wonder if folks sometimes or often gaslight others and are truly conscious of what they're doing. Often when people project, they do so subconsciously.

Comment: This is good advice for neurotypical people as well.

Answer (score 42):

This is more of a huge comment than an answer, but I still wanted to post it anyway.

---

Keep in mind that on Stack Overflow (unlike on a social network), the people are not purposely trying to harm you when an interaction does make you feel bad.

I think there are two main situations because of which you can induce stress to yourself (at least, those were the case for me when I was still asking questions on the main site):

- The first thing is the gamification part of the website. Even though it's nice to receive upvotes and reputations when your content is considered useful, when you get downvoted, and your question gets closed, you feel like you did something wrong, even though you tried hard to do it properly.
- The second thing is when you receive feedback (mostly in the comment section of your post). They can be blunt, but it's not because they hate you, and they're not trying to scold you. They're just trying to tell you the stuff very factually, as a matter of fact. The problem is that Stack Overflow has a lot of stuff posted daily (when I go on the main page and refresh, new stuff keeps appearing every few seconds; it's crazy). If they don't enforce to some extent some criteria for quality, it can go bad really fast.

With that said, I think what is happening is, whenever you are in the process of writing a post, you remember all these details, you are afraid of doing a mistake, and so it's stressing you out.

I remember another post on Meta Stack Overflow mentioning that if you are feeling stressed, then it's a good thing, because it means you're being careful, and you want to do it properly (you can have a look at the answers of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/375702/stress-problems-with-stack-overflow) if you are curious).

But too much stress can be bad, so you should think about your well-being if it's making you sick.

On a final note, don't worry about downvotes on Meta. Unlike the main site, it doesn't mean that it's a bad post.

---

> I want to interact with normal people and become used to it.

Disclaimer: I am in no way an expert, but I still wanted to give my point of view on that specific sentence, from what I've learned by discussing with my friends and others.

It sounds like you are considering yourself as "not normal", as an outcast, when in fact you are as much a human-being as any of us. You merely have some differences, but everyone have their own set of differences.

One of my contacts on LinkedIn mentioned the word "neurodiversity". Since then, it gave me a different outlook of what autism is (i.e., you merely behave differently than a majority of other people).

I understand what you're trying to say by "normal people", but you should be careful not to stomp yourself.

Answer (score 36):

I think that quite some software developers and therefore a [not insignificant](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+insignificant) amount of users here are somewhere [on the spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autism_spectrum) (which is *not* the same as "mentally ill"), so you're not alone in your experience.

There are two very basic questions you need to answer to solve most of your problems:

1. What is it that you want?
2. What do you need to accomplish that?

It looks like what you want is to positively contribute to Stack Overflow. You think you failed in that, because some of your posts were received somewhat negatively, in your opinion.

You talk about "scolding" and "lectures". What it seems you need, is someone who can explain, or translate if you will, those lectures into something you can understand.

So to answer your question's title, *"How do moderators deal with users who have autism or mental problems?"* - they deal with them like everyone else. Be it user moderators who vote, comment or answer or site moderators who do the same and more: they don't care about *you* personally, they care about the content they encounter on the site.

If you provided content, and that content required feedback, they can't tune that feedback to every provider. Ain't nobody got time for that. That is an autism problem, and perhaps a people problem at large.

Look, for example, at education. Does it work for every child to be chucked into a classroom of thirty or so noisy peers, and get taught the same materials as everyone else, at the same speed as everybody else? Hell to the no! Then why do we insist on doing it like that for the better half of a century already? Money perhaps? We usually can't afford one teacher for every two kids.

And Stack Overflow doesn't have a tutor per user. So if you can't "read between the lines" so to say, and extract the expected behavior to "fit in" yourself, then you need to find someone who can help you do that. Perhaps one of your siblings could help, by reading the feedback you received, and explaining to you what they think it means.

Comment: Solid advice overall. Do you have anything to back up your opening claim? This is the first time I've ever heard anyone posit anything like that.

Comment: No, I start with "I think" for a reason. It's my experience, not based on any verifiable facts.

Comment: @zcopp98 Well, we already have [statistics from the developer survey](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/survey/2019#developer-profile-_-disability-status) done here of all places that 2.6% of users are on the spectrum and a _fair_ percentage have some form of mental disorder (from depression, to anxiety, to ADHD) and *"In the United States, almost 30% of respondents said they deal with a mental health challenge"*

Comment: I really like the suggestion about a sibling translating feedback!

Comment: @Nick Maybe so, but 2.6% of users here is a far cry from 50% + 1, which is the minimum necessary for the qualifier "most" to be accurate. IMHO this is quite a surprising (and, so far, a wholly unsubstantiated) claim to make about the users of the site.

Comment: @TylerH Oh, I agree, I was just looking for _some_ source. Re: the edit, significant and not insignificant do not have the exact same meaning (the difference is indeed rather subtle), even if one appears to just be a double negative

Comment: @Nick They do, actually. Something is either significant, or not significant (insignificant). Worse, having a double negative is hard to read, and in a thread about neurodivergence it's probably most important to use language that's easy to parse.

Comment: @TylerH They don't, actually. Significant implies a large amount, insignificant implies a small amount, not significant implies not a large amount but not necessarily a small amount and not insignificant implies not a small amount, but not necessarily a large amount, again, a _subtle_, but important difference. Unfortunately every source I've found indicates that it's just a BrE vs AmE thing.

Comment: @Nick Any subtlety is going to be a subjective thing and, as the discussion here only underscores, something that unnecessarily injects confusion into CodeCaster's response, *especially* given the subject matter/audience under discussion. If this were a scientific paper, I'd perhaps agree there is a worthwhile distinction... in a post on Meta, not likely.

Comment: @TylerH Yeah,... I'm gunna have to disagree on that, the difference between the two changes the meaning of the sentence, but hey-ho, to each their own, will leave it to CodeCaster to see what they prefer

Comment: @Nick it also depends on domain; ["significant" to people from a mathematical or scientific background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_significance) absolutely does not imply a "large amount." I think the wording is fine as-is – definitely "most" was not appropriate.

Comment: @miken32 Indeed it does, to me here the intention is clearly meant to be a small amount, but an amount that is important nonetheless, so both not significant and significant at the same time, the edit changes that intent. But yes, "most" was most certainly incorrect.

Comment: @TylerH "not insignificant" was both a stylistic choice and an idiom; in my native language the equivalent would translate to "not to be ignored/neglected", emphasis on the group maybe not being a majority, but indeed something to be considered. All in all we've spent too many comments here discussing semantics though. I just meant that in my experience from decades in both IT education and IT work, is that the field attracts a certain type of person, which isn't as overrepresented elsewhere.

Comment: Good points overall. This sums up the general blunt approach. To be fair, though, we mods generally *will* attempt to accommodate users to a reasonable extent, but only if brought to our attention. E.g, if you respond with something like, "Thank you for your feedback, but I am having trouble interpreting it constructively. Perhaps it is my <insert label here>, but I am working hard to become a valued member of this community. Could you please explain your remarks to me in another way, keeping in mind my <whatever it is you want us to keep in mind>", then we'll probably engage happily with that

Comment: On a related note, I'm really appreciating the irony of all the grammatical nitpicking in the comments here.

Comment: @Nick: As someone with a pretty serious case of ADHD, I don't feel like it's any kind of obstacle to interacting with people on Stack Overflow. (Except writing long / too many comments that sometimes get "moved to chat" more than I'd like, but I don't have any problem understanding why some moderators think that's a good idea, and it doesn't weigh on me emotionally or anything.) IDK why ADHD is even in the same conversation as the autistic spectrum or depression. The only problem I have is dozens of tabs (and more saved in files) of half-finished answers that I got side-tracked from

Comment: @Peter Cordes: To be fair, there is a significant (albeit not that major) overlap between ADHD and autism. For example, I can relate to what you said about extended comments, dozens of tabs, and getting sidetracked from half-finished answers. But I don't have most of the definitive ADHD traits.

Comment: @BoltClock: As is common with ADHD, I have/had some other learning disabilities which aren't directly part of ADHD (which made school a challenge in younger grades, before finding a school with the right teachers for a few years.)  ADHD is a challenge for managing one's life, etc., but I just want to let everyone know that ADHD specifically is not one of the things that make it harder for random strangers on the Internet to interact with us. (I have to make an effort to *remember* to think about other people's viewpoints, but unlike autism, I don't have trouble picking up queues.)

Comment: @Peter Cordes: That's an excellent point, thanks for sharing. After I finally realized what the original title was I can't help but wonder if editing was the right choice, if the question should've remained specific to autism and mental illness - but hopefully Cody's compromise will help.

Comment: @BoltClock: I think the current title is reasonable.  Not everything that makes people different from "normal" people would produce the same kinds of effects the querent is asking about.  And that's fine; the question body makes it clear what the question is about, and the title doesn't imply anything incorrect. (only people commenting about ADHD in this context :/).  BTW, after some googling, I found https://www.spectrumnews.org/features/deep-dive/decoding-overlap-autism-adhd/ - some researchers have even proposed that ADHD and autism could be different effects of a single underlying cause.

Comment: Anecdote time (bad moderator, chatting in comments): We were very lucky that we could afford “one teacher for three kids” by homeschooling our kids. Look up “unschooling” if you are curious about approach. All our kids are ND, but have found success and fulfilment in their chosen paths (2 are in Uni following their passions and one is still at home but knows where she wants to go next). By which I wanted to say: don’t feel like you have to fit in, there could well be alternatives that work better for you!

Answer (score 5):

An on-the-spectrum contributor here.  For colleagues that don't know this "spectrum" lingo, it means I have some symptoms and habits of autism. I sometimes miss social cues that others find obvious.

Here's what I do to manage this so I can participate here. I follow these rules.

1. Never downvote anything, ever. Dumb answer? Ignore it. Dumb question? The only dumb question is the unasked question.
2. Upvote generously.
3. Stay out of the review queues. Plenty of people with better social cues can do that work.
4. In comments, try to use this formula: "With respect, I think you should go read Kernighan and Ritchie's book on C before taking on a project involving 3D arrays" (or whatever way is polite to say *banish your ignorance and come back so we can help). "With respect" seems to soften criticism.
5. If somebody leaves a negative comment on my work, always write "thanks, I missed that point" in reply.
6. Read the question a couple of times and try (it's hard) to imagine myself in the shoes of the person who wrote it.
7. Remember I was a n00b once too.

It's all about trying to shape my attitude about our colleagues in this community to be positive.

When I do these things I don't get in as much flag / downvote / close trouble.

Comment: _I sometimes miss social cues that others find obvious._ ---> Same but I'm not on the spectrum.

Comment: How does rule #1 of not downvoting solve any problems? I *regularly* miss social cues, but I don't see why that should keep me from expressing my opinion about the relevance, accuracy, or usefulness of a post. Your voice is as valuable as anyone else's. And if you're concerned that you cannot make meaningful judgments about a post's quality, why in the world would you be willing to "upvote generously"? If you're going to upvote, you should also downvote. If you cannot trust yourself to downvote, then you shouldn't trust yourself to vote.

Comment: The points you mention are surely a good recipe for reducing potential friction, but voting is quite anonymous, the first two points should not strongly affect how others see you. "With respect" works well, already the "I think you should" goes a long way. Sometimes I go with "It might be a good idea to...". For the negative comments I tend to differentiate if they are based on some real issue and if they are I definitely also thank the commenter, but if I have the feeling that there is not enough substance in a negative comment, I instead ask for clarification. I always try to stay polite.

Comment: The no-downvotes rule I follow is for *my* benefit, so it doesn't matter that voting is anonymous. Keeps me thinking positively.

Comment: Even with *"With respect"* (#4), it is still [RTFM](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/RTFM#Phrase). Does it really need to be said? Why not just don't comment at all?

Comment: @PeterMortensen there are so many FMs these days that RTFM advice benefits from a pointer to suggested reading. Of course it's wise to ignore questions starting off "I don't know anything about programming and I want to build a better OS."  or that sort of megalomaniacal statement.

Comment: @CodyGray I think O. is saying that for their personal rule, which is admirable. Pretty sure they're more aware of their cognition than you. Please don't take this as criticism; I've seen many posts and comments of yours that are awesome.

Comment: And how exactly is choosing not to downvote considered a "good" or "admirable" personal rule? Being in the spectrum does not impede one to make a proper assessment of quality and usefulness, and future visitors won't benefit from reserving downvotes on posts.

Comment: Autistic people usually have no problem with constructive criticism and are more than happy to make amends. However... we do have a problem with downvotes that 1) don't come with any feedback, *and* 2) it's not immediately clear from the post itself what could be improved. Because if it's not clear what can be improved, how do you expect us to do better next time? And I'm sure neurotypicals whether new or old feel the same way, though without the RSD. Truthfully, I'd rather be scolded with specifics on what I did wrong, than be politely reprimanded with a simple "that's bad" or "that's wrong".

Comment: Downvotes are therefore acceptable to us, provided they come with adequate feedback communicated either by the downvote itself if that's all that's needed, or preferably with a comment, especially if specifics not covered by the tooltip need to be highlighted. **For autistics, explicit, specific feedback is key.** If anything, I'd say we tend to handle downvotes better than our non-autistic peers, even those of us who suffer from anxiety and RSD like Shiz and I do.

Comment: @Kit That's a totally fair point, and I admire anyone who is willing to stand up and defend their principles,, regardless of whether or not I happen to agree with them. I just don't think that this particular principle is internally consistent, and, more importantly, I think that it has the potential to do great harm to the site were it to be followed universally. Quality control only helps if it can work in both directions. If *most* of the stuff you see is good, then, yes, definitely upvote it! But if you see low-quality content, I really want people to feel confident downvoting it.

Comment: @BoltClock I can say with confidence that that's...not a problem unique to autistic people. :-) As you well know, a single downvote means nothing more than "someone else on the Internet thought that this content was not useful, interesting, or correct". Which...yeah, isn't very specific feedback, but isn't necessarily meant to be, either. If someone wanted to give targeted feedback, they could always choose to do so---and many people do leave comments. Downvotes are an entirely different signal, and meant to be more a signal to the *system* than to the individual user.

Comment: @BoltClock "_Autistic people usually have no problem with constructive criticism and are more than happy to make amends_" - From experience teaching SPED, this isn't true. Depending on the person, every little piece of criticism, whether mentioned or imagined, could be an antecedent to escalated behavior. Many of my autistic students required 4:1 positive reinforcement with _no criticism_, as criticizing would escalate behaviors and distract from the lesson. Where did you get "_they usually have no problem with criticism_"? If you're autistic, understand the spectrum is wide.. Can't generalize

Comment: @Dioxin: You're right, can't generalize. My explanation was exceedingly poor. We don't exactly handle criticism well, at least internally. Internally, criticism is associated with frustration, an unexpected change, or even trauma. This can result in the escalations you mention, or other manifestations of RSD depending on our age and coping mechanism. That being said, it's true that we prioritize making amends, that is, our reactions are not in bad faith, but simply because of our internal turmoil. Ultimately, we still want to do what's right. That's probably why we take criticism so seriously.

Comment: I believe O. Jones is giving advice for folks *on the spectrum* about how to participate in Stack Overflow while avoiding interpersonal conflict.  My own upvote to downvote ratio is VERY high, so I can understand his tendency to not go in the downvote direction. But more importantly, there are MANY ways to contribute beyond downvoting on the site.  Yes, downvoting is important.  No, you don't need to feel obliged to downvote if it keeps getting you into situations where you feel extremely anxious.

Comment: "missing social cues" is pretty normal for everyone when all you have to deal with is text as you miss the most important signals that people send out (tone of voice, body posture, hand gestures, facial expression). Hence we minimise the need; neutrality and content-driven interactions are the norm, not social ones. In that respect I would think that people on the spectrum should have a slightly easier time on Stack Overflow than on other websites... but it's clearly more complicated than that.