# Can we discuss the minimum 6-character requirement for editing a post?

Tags: discussion, edits, formatting

I've fallen into this trap the past couple of days. The edits I couldn't make were:

- add a tag to a post to help draw people to a post asking a specific question (I wanted to add the regex code to a regex and R question - there was only the R tag on the question)
- format a questioner's ggplot code using so it wasn't a wide line of

  ```
   [code] + [code] + [code] + [code]
  ```

(there was literally a lot of scrolling sideways), but was instead

```
[code] +
[code] +
[code] +
[code]
```

there were more than four lots of `[code] +` and it was quite difficult to read

- format a code block for a questionner so their code was in a block.

In each case my edits were rejected because I hadn't used enough characters. I'm not even sure that hard returns were counted, for trying to get that `ggplot` question formatted.

Am I restricted by rep for being unable to make short edits such as these? I expected that once I received edit privileges I would be able to make suitable edits. Surely formatting code so that is easily readable falls within the scope of reasonable editing?

[I see this exact question has been asked/point has been raised in the past.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252249/what-is-wrong-with-minor-edits) Is there an updated commentary on it?

Does anyone like scrolling horizontally through code that is better on multiple lines?

Comment: Are you certain there were no grammar or spelling issues in the post?

Comment: I for one think it's a stupid rule and only encourages frivolous, yet mandatory embellishments to edits. If this were a democracy (which it isn't) I'd vote to do away with the 6 char minimum.

Comment: Are you sure you can’t suggest tag only edits? I think those are exempted from the minimum character count (as long as the count is 0).

Comment: If you try to edit less than 6 characters, does the error message on that explain why it rejects the edit, like in [this answer below](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397436/509868)? Or does it just say "less than 6 characters = error"?

Comment: *format a code block for a questionner so their code was in a block* - If you use the code fence, 3 back ticks to start and 3 to close it, the that’s already 6 characters. If you add a language for code highlighting then you’re past that. If you are indenting by four spaces instead then that’s 8 characters if there’s 2 lines. I have seen plenty of edits in the queue lately that format code and nothing else so this is definitely possible.

Comment: I use “[Decision &] Edit” much more often than “Approve” or “Reject” so while it does happen that a well written post has a one character typo, it’s too rare in the review queue to justify changing the rule.

Comment: @BSMP the code was already formatted as a code block, it had no line returns in it. My 5 hard returns didn't count.

Comment: @anatolyg it just give s the less than 6 characters error. These all only give the 6 characters error.

Comment: @yivi I'm trying to remember. It was a well-written post, that only had the one tag. As far as I recall, I only tried to add the one tag.

Comment: You probably misremember. Just editing a tag does not check the character limit. But if you make **any** other edit to the post, the change need to be at least 6 characters long.

Answer (score 10):

> Can we discuss the minimum 6-character requirement for editing a post?

Sure, let's discuss it. I'm strongly in favor of it, and always have been.

If you want to persuade me to reconsider, please find a minimum of two (2) examples of posts so perfect that fewer than 6 characters need to be changed—where there is simply nothing else that can stand to be improved. I haven't found any such posts yet.

> Does anyone like scrolling horizontally through code that is better on multiple lines?

No, obviously everyone hates that. There is a special circle in hell for designers of UIs with horizontal scroll bars. But that is a straw man relative to character minimums for edits. You can fix that in an edit, and you should also fix *other* issues with the post.

By the way, edits that *only* change the tags of a question are accepted. The 6-character minimum only applies when you start editing the body of the post. The idea is, **if you're going to edit, *make it count***. Why does that matter? Well, at least three other people will have to take time to review and vote on your edit, which is time that *they* could be spending to improve the site. Reviewing superfluous or incomplete edits is not a good use of reviewers' time, and making such edits is not a good use of your time.

Comment: This is where we will disagree. I will not edit posts for the sake of editing them. I am not editing posts for trivial spelling errors, or grammatical errors, where the meaning is clear. If editors should be doing that, then we'll spend a lot of time editing most posts. Some people just appear to either 1. be extremely bad at producing good quality code blocks or 2. be too lazy to fix it after previewing the question.